# Toggle Sidebar visibility and Toggle Panel visiblity together in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I want to make a keybinding:

1. When the sidebar is visible, the bottom panel is not visible,
   press to hide the sidebar, press again to show both.
2. When the sidebar is not visible, the bottom panel is visible, press to hide the bottom panel, press again to show both.
3. When the sidebar is visible, the bottom panel is visible, press to hide both, press again to show both.
4. When the sidebar is not visible, the bottom panel is not visible, press to show both, press again to hide both.

With tools I know the command

> Toggle Panel
> Toggle Side Bar Visibility

How to do this in Vscode?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, but **only** with the help of a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) or by writing your own extension.  Since you need to run 2 commands at a time in some cases - like closing or opening both views at the same time.

In your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+1",                 // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.togglePanel",
      "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    ]
  },
  "when": "panelVisible && sideBarVisible || !panelVisible && !sideBarVisible"
},

{
  "key": "alt+1",           // use same keybinding here
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.togglePanel"
    ]
  },
  "when": "panelVisible && !sideBarVisible"
},

{
  "key": "alt+1",           // use same keybinding here
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
    ]
  },
  "when": "!panelVisible && sideBarVisible"
}
```

---

There are also these commands

```
workbench.action.closePanel
workbench.action.closeSidebar
```

but I don't see them helping in your case.

Comment: thank you, I spell wrong, should be "press to show both", then "press to hide both"

Answer (score 1):

Multiple commands are now [supported natively](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177722).

Adding something like the following to `keybindings.json`:

```json
[
    // Existing shortcuts...

    { // hide or show all help-bars
        "key": "ctrl+h",
        "command": "runCommands", 
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
                "workbench.action.togglePanel"
            ]
        }
    },

    // Existing shortcuts...
]
```